# Caret within parenthesis in RewriteRule

Tags: mod-rewrite, regex

What does this mean:

```
RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
```

I know the F flag means to throw a 403 forbidden error.  And I know the escaped period means that directories starting with a period are forbidden.  But what is the meaning of the caret, pipe and slash within the parenthesis?  What would be the difference between the statement above and this one:

```
RewriteRule "\." - [F]
```

What if I wanted to flag URLs as forbidden when they start with a period but with an exception for this directory:

```
.well-known
```

**Update**:  It looks like I can satisfy the latter requirement with...

```
RewriteRule "(^|/)\.(?!well-known)" - [F]
```

I'm still wondering what is the meaning of the caret, pipe and slash within the parenthesis.

Comment: The caret usually signifies the beginning (of a string or line or variable etc) and I think the `|` is an OR, so it would be looking for `^.` a full stop at the beginning (root) or `/.` in the middle. (but making a full stop in another place ok - `/sksks.sks/okplace`)

Comment: Does (^|/) mean something like "nothing at all or a forward slash"?  If so, why would we need to express the "nothing at all" part?

Comment: For root folders beginning with a `.` with no leading `/` ?

Comment: "directories starting with a period are forbidden" - more commonly _files_ (eg. `.htaccess`). But in reality _any URL-path segment_ that starts with a period (which may or may not map to a physical file or directory). Unless you have specific dot-files you need to block access (which is best done with a `<FilesMatch>` container and mod_authz_core) then this directive may not be required anyway? The server should already have directives that block `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd`-like files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^` and `$` are special characters that represent the beginning and end of strings (or lines)

the `|` is an `OR` symbol

`(^|/)\.` expands to  `^.` **or** `/.` (without escaping slash for clarity)

`^.` = any string that has a `.` as the first character

`/.` = any string with a `/.`

Comment: I was editing this while you were ArnoldBird - it says the edits conflicted - Please go ahead and edit now if still needed.

Comment: Is it worth adding the part of the answer you found yourself? (about all forbidden except <x>)